# Find zip files in all directories but exclude some folders

Tags: linux, terminal, find

I want to see all zip files in `/home` directory on my server and all users folders too,
but I want to exclude the `'.composer/`' and `'vendor/'` folders that may or may not exist on clients directories

i start with :

```
find . -iname \*.zip -prune -o -path "./composer*/*"
```

but doesn't work as i expected

returned ex:

```
./pescador/.composer/cache/files/mpdf/mpdf/30bed8bf2e5584fafe3dd19a2fb7d17e522e7402.zip
./pescador/.composer/cache/files/mpdf/mpdf/04966b62554c455cb7639829734133fbc0ad3228.zip
```

But i can't exlude all dot directories, because i want search on .trash too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -path './composer*' -prune -o -iname '*.zip' -print
```

Though that would not list `./composer-foo.ZIP` for instance.

For that you could word it:

```
find . '(' ! -path './composer*' -o -prune ')' -iname '*.zip'
```

`-prune` tells `find` not to descend into a directory, so you want to apply that to the directories you want to script. and `-print` the files you want to be listed (note that if no action predicate is specified (and `-prune` is *not* an action predicate), an implicit `-print` action is added, for the files that match the whole expression).

But here, it looks like you want to skip the directories that are called `.composer` wherever they are, not direct sub-directories of the current working directory whose name starts with `composer`, so that'd just be:

```
find . -name .composer -prune -o -iname '*.zip' -print
```

Or to also skip directories called `vendor`:

```
find . '(' -name .composer -o -name vendor ')' -prune \
       -o -iname '*.zip' -print
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the -v flag of grep to exclude the unwanted results:

```
# find /home -iname *.zip|grep -v "./composer"|grep -v "vendor/"
```

Comment: That will still search through those directories hierachies, which might take a long time (a common reason for wanting to skip directories when searching for files). So it's better to learn the proper use of '-prune', as in Stéphane's answer.

Comment: as Henrik says it will search on directories that i want to exclude
and i have a lot folders to run this search